# How can I destroy the previous instance of object and create new one whenever a function is called?

Tags: vb.net, vsto

Whenever a user selects a cell in a sheet I want a windows form to appear and any previous windows form that was connected to the previously active cell to be dissapear. How can I do this?

I'm thinking a solution like the following would work, but I don't know if it is good practice and I also don't know how to execute the command that I have commented out

```
Sub CreateNewFormForActiveCellAndDeleteThePreviousOne()
    'Remove all previous instances of class Frm
    Dim Frm as New Frm
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you just store the reference in a private field? Inside the method, check if the field is not null. If true, destroy the window. Then create a new window, store the reference and return the instance.

Comment: From my understanding, doing it as you show above should work fine. Each time the sub is called, a new instance of `Frm` is created. When the sub exits, the object loses it's reference (assuming no variables are set to hold it inside the sub where the variables scope are outside of the sub), which causes it to be marked for cleanup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new form instance I'd suggest updating the data on the form instead. Thus, you will save resources required for creating a new form instance. For example, you may define a public field in the Form's class and update it according to the selected cell in Excel.